# using simple injector in mvc6 with cookie auth

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, simple-injector

I have a MVC6 project using simple injector and cookie middleware for authentication **without** ASP.NET identity (tutorials below)

http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html

I have a custom `SignInManager` / `UserManager` that wraps `PrincipalContext` to validate windows credentials (SideNote: I am not using the Azure AD with aspnet 5 because [in the future] I know there will be a mix of windows and non windows usernames. Plus I could not get permissions to do so in enough time). My initial issue was injecting `IHttpContextAccessor` into the `SignInManager` and `CookieAuthenticationOptions` into both classes. I kept receiving the error below:

> no authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: ThisCompany.Identity

To solve my issue I had to get the `IHttpContextAccessor` from asp.net services and then register it with simple injector. This worked, but seemed wrong and maybe there is another way to do it. So, is this wrong? If so, I was hoping others have tried this and can chime in with another solution if it exists. Below are abbreviated versions of my classes:

```
  public class Startup
  {
    public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration;
    private readonly Container container = new Container();
    private readonly AppSettings settings;
    private readonly CookieAuthenticationOptions cookieOptions;

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
    {
      // config builder here...

      cookieOptions = createCookieOptions();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      // other stuff here...

      services.AddInstance<IControllerActivator>(new SimpleInjectorControllerActivator(container));
      services.AddInstance<IViewComponentInvokerFactory>(new SimpleInjectorViewComponentInvokerFactory(container));
      services.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Instance<IHttpContextAccessor>(new NeverNullHttpContextAccessor()));
    }

    public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
      app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOptions);

      #region DI

      container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AspNetRequestLifestyle();
      container.Options.LifestyleSelectionBehavior = new ScopeLifestyleSelectionBehavior();
      app.UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping(container);
      InitializeContainer(app);

      // this is the part I am unsure about
      var accessor = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();                    
      container.Register(() => accessor, Lifestyle.Scoped);

      container.RegisterAspNetControllers(app);
      container.RegisterAspNetViewComponents(app);
      container.Verify();

      #endregion

      using (var scope = SimpleInjectorExecutionContextScopeExtensions.BeginExecutionContextScope(container))
      {
        // seed cache and dummy data
      }
    }

    private void InitializeContainer(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
      var conn = new SqlConnection(Configuration["Data:AppMainConnection"]);

      // bunch of registrations...

      container.RegisterSingleton(() => cookieOptions);
    }

    private sealed class NeverNullHttpContextAccessor : IHttpContextAccessor
    {
      private readonly AsyncLocal<HttpContext> context = new AsyncLocal<HttpContext>();

      public HttpContext HttpContext
      {
        get { return context.Value ?? new DefaultHttpContext(); }
        set { context.Value = value; }
      }
    }

    private sealed class ScopeLifestyleSelectionBehavior : ILifestyleSelectionBehavior
    {
      public Lifestyle SelectLifestyle(Type serviceType, Type implementationType)
      {
        return Lifestyle.Scoped;
      }
    }
    private CookieAuthenticationOptions createCookieOptions()
    {
      return new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
      {
        AuthenticationScheme = "ThisCompany.Identity",
        AutomaticChallenge = true,
        AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Auth/Login/"),
        LogoutPath = new PathString("/Auth/Logout"),
        AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Auth/Forbidden/"), // TODO
        CookieName = "yumyum.net",
        SlidingExpiration = true,
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
        Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
        {
          OnRedirectToAccessDenied = ctx =>
          {
            if (ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") && ctx.Response.StatusCode == 200)
            {
              ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            }
            else
            {
              ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
          }
        }
      };
    }
```

And here is the `SignInManager` (I won't show the `UserManager`, that wraps my repo,`PrincipalContext` and claims creation:

```
  public class SignInManager : ISignInManager
  {
    private readonly IUserManager userManager;
    private readonly HttpContext context;
    private readonly CookieAuthenticationOptions options;

    public SignInManager(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, IUserManager userManager, CookieAuthenticationOptions options)
    {
      if (contextAccessor == null || contextAccessor.HttpContext == null)
      {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(contextAccessor));
      }
      if (options == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));   
      if (userManager == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userManager));

      context = contextAccessor.HttpContext;
      this.userManager = userManager;
      this.options = options;
    }

    public async Task<bool> PasswordSignInAsync(string user, string password, bool isPersistent)
    {
      if (user == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));

      if (await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, password))
      {
        await signInAsync(user, isPersistent);
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    }

    public async Task SignOutAsync() => await context.Authentication.SignOutAsync(options.AuthenticationScheme);

    private async Task signInAsync(string user, bool isPersistent)
    {
      var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = isPersistent };
      var userPrincipal = await userManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
      if (userPrincipal == null) throw new InvalidOperationException($"{user} not found");

        // this is where the error was happening
        await context.Authentication.SignInAsync(options.AuthenticationScheme,
          new ClaimsPrincipal(userPrincipal),
          authenticationProperties);
     }
  }
```

**UPDATE**

Here are the details when I added `container.CrossWire<IHttpContextAccessor>(app);` and remove

```
  var accessor = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();                    
  container.Register(() => accessor, Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Exception: the `ISignInManager` is injected into my `AuthController` as scoped since `AuthController` is scoped too:

```
SimpleInjector.DiagnosticVerificationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=The configuration is invalid. The following diagnostic warnings were reported:
-[Lifestyle Mismatch] SignInManager (ASP.NET Request) depends on IHttpContextAccessor (Transient).
See the Error property for detailed information about the warnings. Please see https://simpleinjector.org/diagnostics how to fix problems and how to suppress individual warnings.
  Source=SimpleInjector
  StackTrace:
       at SimpleInjector.Container.ThrowOnDiagnosticWarnings()
       at SimpleInjector.Container.Verify(VerificationOption option)
       at SimpleInjector.Container.Verify()
       at Startup.<Configure>d__7.MoveNext() in ... line 109
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_1(Object state)
       at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
       at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
       at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
  InnerException:
```

**UPDATE**

I am sure I will be corrected if this is not correct, but I went with @Steven's answer for an adapter. I guess this was more of a lesson of design patterns that I was not too familiar with. Here is my new class and registration below that I will use in my custom SignInManager:

```
  public class DefaultAuthenticationManager : IAuthenticationManager
  {
    private readonly HttpContext context;

    public DefaultAuthenticationManager(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
      if (accessor == null || accessor.HttpContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(accessor));

      context = accessor.HttpContext;
    }

    public Task SignInAsync(string authenticationScheme, ClaimsPrincipal principal, AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
      return context.Authentication.SignInAsync(authenticationScheme, principal, properties);
    }

    public Task SignOutAsync(string authenticationScheme)
    {
     return  context.Authentication.SignOutAsync(authenticationScheme);
    }
  }


private void InitializeContainer(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
     var accessor = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();

     container.Register<IAuthenticationManager>(() => new DefaultAuthenticationManager(accessor), Lifestyle.Scoped);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CrossWire` extension method in the integration package makes a delegate registration in Simple Injector that allows Simple Injector to 'know' about the service, while the ASP.NET 5 configuration system is still in control of building that service. You can do the same yourself as follows:

```
container.Register(() => app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<ISomeService>());
```

The `CrossWire` extension method seems rather useless, since it seems a one-liner to do it yourself, but CrossWire does one extra thing, which is suppressing the diagnostic warning that is thrown when a transient component implements IDisposable. This works around design flaws in ASP.NET 5, because there are abstractions in ASP.NET 5 that implement IDisposable, while abstractions should never implement IDisposable (abstractions that do, violate the Dependency Inversion Principle).

But this brings me to the next point, `CrossWire` always makes the registration in Simple Injector as transient, even though in ASP.NET the registration might be scoped or singleton. Which lifestyle a component has in ASP.NET is often an implementation detail, and might change from time to time. Or at least, the lifestyle is unknown to both the user and Simple Injector. That's why it is safest to give all cross-wired registrations the transient lifestyle by default. This does mean however that all dependent application components should be transient as well to prevent Captive Dependencies (a.k.a. Lifestyle Mismatches). I would say this is typically not a problem, because application components that depend ASP.NET services are very ASP.NET related. It's unlikely that you have core application components depend on ASP.NET stuff, because that would violate the Dependency Inversion Principle and might lead to hard to maintain code.

In your case you can do a few things. Simplest thing to do is to make SignInManager transient as well. It seems unlikely that it has any state that it should maintain over a single request, and when it does, that state should probably not belong there anyway (Single Responsibility Violation).

Another option is to cross wire the IHttpContextAccessor as singleton in Simple Injector. This is valid, because this service is registered as singleton in ASP.NET as well. This won't cause any hidden Captive Dependencies (unless Microsoft changes the lifetime in the future; in that case we're all screwed). You can do it like this:

```
container.RegisterSingleton(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>());
```

Your third option is to prevent registration of this IHttpContextAccessor completely. It is by itself already a Dependency Inversion Principle violation for your application code. It's a DIP violation, because IHttpContextAccessor is not defined by your application but by the framework. It will therefore never be defined in a way that exactly suits your application needs. Your application code will hardly ever need to get a HttpContext object. Rather it is interested in some particular value such as a UserId, TenantId, or other contextual value. So instead, your application is much better of when it depends on an IUserContext, ITenantContext or other specific abstraction. Whether or not the value is extracted from the HttpContext is an implementation detail.

Such implementation (adapter) can resolve the IHttpContextAccessor at runtime and get the HttpContext from it. The implementation of such adapter would most of the time be really simple of course, but this is fine; our goal is simply to shield the application from this knowledge. Since the adapter has knowledge about the ASP.NET abstraction, it is fine for it to resolve services from it configuration. The adapter is merely an anti-corruption layer.

These are basically your options.

Comment: thanks @Steven. My SignInManager only uses the `HttpContext.Autentication` property to sign in and sign out.  I like you anti-corruption idea. Is the best way to get the `IHttpContextAccessor` at startup and inject it into my adapter which holds the Authentication class?

Comment: @JayMichael Since the IHttpContextAdapter is a singleton, you can easily resolve it once at startup from ASP.NET and create an adapter instance that you register in SI. Otherwise you would resolve the Accessor at runtime on each call

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar in order to register `IdentityOptions` and `IDataProtectionProvder` with simpleinjector to get some authentication things to work. I don't *think* it's "wrong", but I could be, and I'm sure Steven will chime in with his canonical opinion to set us both on the right path.

One minor difference was that I did not provide an `IApplicationBuilder` instance to my `InitializeContainer` method, only the `IServiceProvider` (which is also available via the `IApplicationBuilder.ApplicationServices` property). Do you really need the whole `IApplicationBuilder` in order to initialize the container?

Comment: yea I was hoping @Steven would too, but thanks for your help. It puts my mind more at ease. As for the `IApplicationBuilder`, the only reason I had it there was to for `container.CrossWire<ILoggerFactory>(app);`,

Comment: Aha. I actually started my project before steven posted those docs. I registered `ILoggerFactory` separately with the application using an `IPackage`. Then again, I don't use full asp.net identity, not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

You should be able to suppress the diagnostic warning in this instance (I am unable to get the code working enough to confirm it tonight though sorry)

```
container.CrossWire<IHttpContextAccessor>(app);
var registration = container.GetRegistration(
    typeof(IHttpContextAccessor)).Registration;
registration.SuppressDiagnosticWarning(
    DiagnosticType.LifestyleMismatch, "Owned by ASP.NET");
```

---

It looks to me like your registration will always return the same instance of `accessor`.

1. resolve an instance of `IHttpContextAccessor`:

   `var accessor = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();`
2. register a delegate to always return the same instance:

   `container.Register(() => accessor, Lifestyle.Scoped);`

I suggest you avoid complicating your registrations by trying to manage the lifetime of objects you do not own and rely on `CrossWire`

```
container.CrossWire<IHttpContextAccessor>(app);
```

Comment: i have tried this and I run into a lifestyle mismatch. In the simple injector example `services.Add(ServiceDescriptor.Instance<IHttpContextAccessor>(new NeverNullHttpContextAccessor()));` registers it as transient and not scoped. If i change it to `services.AddScoped(sp => ServiceDescriptor.Instance<IHttpContextAccessor>(new NeverNullHttpContextAccessor()));` then i get the `contextAccessor` is null error

Comment: Can you show the details of the lifestyle mismatch?

Comment: yes let me update my question to include "what I have tried"