# Adding bearer token to dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, identityserver4, bearer-token

I have identity server 4 setup and my mvc client redirects to identity server and I can authenticate the user.

Now if I want to call me API I can do the following. However I have to pass the access token into the method that calls my api.

Controller

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var accessToken = await HttpContext.Authentication.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

        var user = _userService.Get(accessToken);
        return View();
    }
}
```

Service

```
public async Task<User> Get(string accessToken)
{
    var result =  await _baseUrl.AppendPathSegment("/v1/User/Get").WithOAuthBearerToken(accessToken).GetJsonAsync<User>();

    return result;
}
```

What I would prefer to do is add the access token to the dependency injection pipeline so that I can use it as a global in the class and not have to worry about passing it around with every call.

```
public class UserService
{
    private readonly string _bearerToken {get;set;}

    public UserService(IOptions<UserSettings> userSettings)
    {
        _bearerToken  = userSettings.Value.BearerToken;
    }

    public async Task<User> Get(string accessToken)
    {
        var result =  await _baseUrl.AppendPathSegment("/v1/User/Get").WithOAuthBearerToken(_bearerToken ).GetJsonAsync<User>();

        return result;
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is the right way of doing it? If it is then I'm not sure how. I thought maybe as part of the OnTokenValidated event.

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
    // Other settings here

    Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnTokenValidated = context =>
        {
            var accessToken = context.SecurityToken as JwtSecurityToken;

            if (accessToken != null)
            {
                // Over here add the accessToken to IOptions<UserSettings>
            }

            return Task.CompletedTask;
         }
   },
}
```

Is the OnTokenValidated event the right place to do it? Would that maintain the token between page loads or is there some other place I should be doing this?
How would I go about adding the accessToken into IOptions or something equivalent?

Thanks

M

Answer (score 1):

After some more investigating I found a way to do it. Using this answer here

[using simple injector in mvc6 with cookie auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657983/using-simple-injector-in-mvc6-with-cookie-auth)

and looking how

https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers

did it I created an ITokenManager and an TokenManager and then had access to IHttpContextAccessor through DI which allows me to get the token.